# Changing localhost port of react-refine

Tags: reactjs, react-refine

How do I open react-refine app on localhost 3000? It opened on port 5173 by default. I looked for it in `package.json` file but can't find port

Answer (score 2):

You can define the port in the [command line arguments](https://refine.dev/docs/packages/documentation/cli/#dev-start-build), for example `npm run refine dev --port 3001`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your port number to the `dev` script in `package.json`,:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "refine dev --port 3000", // Add port no. here
    "build": "tsc && refine build",
    "preview": "refine start",
    "refine": "refine"
  },
```